# Prove sum of T(Xi) also belong to exponential family

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

In mathematical statistics, suppose we have an independent and identically distributed sample X = ($X_1$, $X_2$, …, $X_n$) from a distribution that belongs to the exponential family. Say we can write  f(x; Θ) = h(x)exp{a(θ)T(x) + b(θ)} since the distribution of each $X_i$ belongs to a the exponential family. How can we prove that the distribution of T(X) and $\sum_{i=1}^n{T(X_i)}$ also belong to exponential family? I took this course a year ago and remembered that it’s just one small step that I couldn’t figure out, now I met some similar materials and this question came to my mind again but I still can’t get it. Could anyone help me with a good step to start?

Comment: Something is a bit unclear to me. If you are saying that each $X_i$ comes from the exponential family form you have above (assuming a single parameter), then doesn't $T(X)=\sum(T(X_i))$? Unless that T(X) is meant to refer to the function of a single variable X?

Comment: To be clearer, it seems like you are simultaneously referring to $T(X)$ as a function of a vector and of a single random variable.